# PHP Selenium Webdriver read browser output

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on some Selenium PHP Webdriver test cases, where I need to grab browser output and assert if certain elements are present in output or not.

For example I've following output types:

.txt output

.json output

and in certain cases

.xml/.rdf.xml output

url will look something like :

http://example.com/api/user/contacts/year/2014.txt OR

http://example.com/api/user/contacts/year/2014.json OR

http://example.com/api/user/contacts/year/2014.xml

now, depending upon output type requested and user credentials, all of these output will contain slightly different values. 
I want to read everything from screen and depending upon scenario, parse the output and do the assertions.

There is no *//body* or *//html* so I can't something like :

```
$this->getActualOutput()
```

OR

```
$this->getElementTextByID()
```

I just need screen output to assert. Can somebody help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not using `curl` instead ?

Comment: Download the file in question using standard php code, and then parse it as the appropriate type (txt, json, whatever) using standard php code. Do not use WebDriver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some R&D, I tried with page source and it works. So anyone struggling with this can use:

```
 $this->getPageSource()
```

and parse the page source to make whatever assertions they want to.